# Rust: modify a String in a procedure

Tags: pointers, rust

I am trying to get familiar with Rust, and currently I'm tackling Rust pointers. I try to implement a function that modifies a String that was defined outside the procedure's scope (just to see if I can do it), but what perfectly works for integers:

```
fn increment(x: &mut int)
{
  *x += 1;
}

fn main()
{
  let mut y = 5i;
  increment(&mut y);
}
```

somehow fails for Strings:

```
fn modify_string(x: &mut String)
{
  *x.push_str(" I was modified somewhere else.");
}

fn main()
{
  let mut mod_str = "I was created in main(), and then".to_string();
  modify_string(&mut mod_str);
}
```

with the following:

```
Compiling hello_world v0.0.1 (file:///mnt/hgfs/projects/rust)
./src/main.rs:26:3: 26:49 error: type `()` cannot be dereferenced
./src/main.rs:26   *x.push_str(" I was modified somewhere else.");
                                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
error: aborting due to previous error
```

I guess there's something about the String type in Rust that I don't get. Where does the 'unit type'

> ()

come from? And, ultimately, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to apply `*` to `x` before calling [`push_str`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.push_str), as the first argument of `push_str` is `&mut String`.

As a result, `*x.push_str("");` is actually parsed as `*(x.push_str(""))` and since `push_str` returns `()`, it fails because you cannot apply `*` to `()`.